# NoneType при пустом списке в Python

Tags: python, типы

Изучаю Python, пишу в виде учебного проекта To-Do list.
Столкнулся с проблемой: Python открывается работать с пустыми списками, выдает ошибку:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Понятно, что пустой объект выдает такое, но если мне он нужен исходно пустым, то как с ним работать позже? Или подскажите, где я не правильно делаю.

Код программы:

```
import shelve

def addNewTask(taskArticle, taskDescribe, taskDeadline, taskPriority):
    tasklistArticles.append(taskArticle)
    tasklistDescribes.append(taskDescribe)
    tasklistDeadlines.append(taskDeadline)
    tasklistPriorities.append(taskPriority)
    db = shelve.open("save", flag='n', protocol=None, writeback=False)
    db["articles"] = tasklistArticles
    db["describes"] = tasklistDescribes
    db["deadlines"] = tasklistDeadlines
    db["priorities"] = tasklistPriorities
    db.close()
    return

tasklistArticles = []
tasklistDescribes = []
tasklistDeadlines = []
tasklistPriorities = []
listLength = 0

db = shelve.open("save", flag='n', protocol=None, writeback=False)
tasklistArticles = db.get("articles")
tasklistDescribes = db.get("describes")
tasklistDeadlines = db.get("deadlines")
tasklistPriorities = db.get("priorities")
db.close()

while True:

    if(tasklistArticles==None):
        command = input("Список задач пуст. Введите [+] для создания задачи\n")
    else:
        listLength = len(tasklistArticles)
        for i in range(listLength):
            print("\n", tasklistArticles[i])
            command = input("Введите номер задачи или [+] для создания новой\n")

    if (command=="+"):
        taskArticle = input("Заголовок задачи:\n")
        taskDescribe = input("Описаниее задачи:\n")
        taskDeadline = input("Дедлайн:\n")
        taskPriority = input("Приоритет (от 0 до 10):\n")
        addNewTask(taskArticle, taskDescribe, taskDeadline, taskPriority)
    elif(int(command)<=listLength):
        print("\n-----\n", tasklistArticles[int(command)], "\n", tasklistDescribes[int(command)], "\n", tasklistDeadlines[int(command)],"\n", tasklistPriorities[int(command)], "\n-----\n")
    elif(int(command)>listLength):
        print("Неверный номер задачи")
    else:
        print("Ошибка: неизвестная команда")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не пустой список, у вас `None` получается в переменных после вызова функции `get`, так как вы не указали иного значения по умолчанию.

Измените строчки:

```
tasklistArticles = db.get("articles")
tasklistDescribes = db.get("describes")
tasklistDeadlines = db.get("deadlines")
tasklistPriorities = db.get("priorities")
```

на:

```
tasklistArticles = db.get("articles", [])
tasklistDescribes = db.get("describes", [])
tasklistDeadlines = db.get("deadlines", [])
tasklistPriorities = db.get("priorities", [])
```

А строку:

```
if(tasklistArticles==None):
```

На строку:

```
if not tasklistArticles:
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы путаете пустой список и None. У пустого списка есть атрибуты, а вот у None атрибута append точно нет. Поэтому после того, как вы убедились, что объект равен None, надо создать новый список. Кроме того, так как вы изменяете объект в функции, то чтобы получить доступ к глобальному объекту, надо использовать global

```
def addNewTask(taskArticle, taskDescribe, taskDeadline, taskPriority):
    global tasklistArticles
...
while True
    ...
    if(tasklistArticles==None):
        tasklistArticles = []
        command = input("Список задач пуст. Введите [+] для создания задачи\n")
```